# Maintaining SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows 10

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-10

I have to run SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows 10 but [it is not supported](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2681562) and so I am not getting any updates. Installing a later version of SQL Server is not an option. I can find all the service packs and cumulative updates online.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a way to get updates automatically?
2. If not, do I have to install all the service packs in sequence, or can I install only the most recent.

Comment: Btw. why do you run SQL Server on a desktop system?

Comment: @BuahahaXD development machine?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 1. Is there a way to get updates automatically?

SQL Server 2008 R2 is [not supported on Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/sql/general/use-sql-server-in-windows). This means the SQL Server team will not be releasing any security updates or patches if they find any specific issues related to SQL Server 2008 R2 code. There is no way to get updates automatically as none would be released related to Windows 10.

Having said that, SQL Server 2008 R2 installation is not *blocked* when you try to install it on Windows 10. Of course, it is always better and advisable to install the latest Service Pack ([Service Pack 3](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44271) is the [final SP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlreleaseservices/update-on-the-service-pack-plans-for-sql-server-2008-and-sql-server-2008-r2) for 2008 R2).

If you are trying to install SQL Server 2008 R2 for testing purpose on Windows 10, you can go ahead; but since it's not supported it would be of no use to carry forward this idea.

> 2. If not, do I have to install all the service packs in sequence, or can I install only the most recent?

Service Packs are cumulative, so you can directly install SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3 even on RTM bits. There are cumulative updates (CU) released after 2008 R2 SP3 as well, but my advice is don't install CU unless you face specific issues fixed in the CU.

Answer (score 1):

SPs are cumulative and once you install the latest, you have by implication, installed all the previous as well.
But when you install the earliest SP, then you have to install the subsequent SP as well which does not make enough wisdom.
Just install the latest and you are good to go.

Answer (score -2):

it is better to install the latest SP as it is supposed to include all previous SPs and the CU from the previous SP till this last one

Some thoigh, SPs do not include ALL the CUs.
If a specific one is fixing an issue you face, then install it.

here is a list you may find useful
http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.ie/